# Plotting Unit Circle in Python with contour

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm trying to plot a circle with contour function. My code looks like as follow,

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def Circle(x,y):
    return (x*x+y*y)

xx=np.linspace(-2,2,400)
yy=np.linspace(-2,2,400)
[X,Y]=np.meshgrid(xx,yy)

Z=Circle(X,Y)

plt.figure()
plt.contour(X,Y,Z,1)
plt.show()
```

I'm thinking the contour function would just provide me the cross section of x^2+y^2=1, but it gives me a circle with different radius of 1.5. Why is that?
Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
plt.contour(X,Y,Z,1)
```

to this:

```
plt.contour(X,Y,Z,[1])
```

If the fourth argument is an integer, it determines the number of levels for which a contour is draw, and `contour` chooses the values for those levels.  If the fourth argument is a sequence, the values in the sequence are the levels of the contours.